# Problems with Dispatcher.Invoke and thread access

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, multithreading, thread-safety

I've trying to handle threads in C#, but i've occurred in a wierd exception I don't know how to resolve. I've got a method running by BackgroundWorker, in which there's this piece of code:

```
GridView gridView;
DataView dataView;

queryTable.GetViewAndDataView(out gridView, out dataView);

this.listView.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(
    delegate() {
        listViewView = gridView;                    
        listView.ItemsSource = dataView;
    }
));
```

GetViewAndDataView fills a gridView and dataView, while the delegate code sets the current listView. The using of Invoke is supposed not to raise exceptions, but when I try to run it, I obtain this: **The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it**.

Anyone knows of to handle such exception, or at least, how to disable the thread object owning?

Comment: What exactly are GridView and DataView?  Is/Has GridView a Control?

Comment: Are the GridView and DataView UI components, or your own classes?

Comment: yep, GridView is a UI components it seems

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The message is correct, you cant create the controls on a background thread and use them on your UI Thread. You have to both create and assign them on your UI thread. I recommend loading your data first in your background thread followed by doing the rest of your work in the UI Thread

Comment: thanks, I've changed the structure of my code reflecting your advices, and now all run fine! :)

Answer (score 2):

You need save `this.listView.Dispatcher` to some local variable before you run the parallel thread. In the thred you must use dispatcher from this variable.

However [@Polity is right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030376/problems-with-dispatcher-invoke-and-thread-access/6030441#6030441) - you must create controls/elements on UI thread. In parallel threads you can create only non-UI objects.